# add to cart how to seperate products

Tags: php, html, forms

```html
<form method="POST" action="" name="prodctlist">
    <ul class="itemlist">

        <li class="itemwrapper product-14587">
            <div class="itempart thumbnail"><img src="..."/></div>
            <div class="itempart pinfo">
                <div class="title"><h5>Product Title</h5></div>
                <div class="description">Product Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="itempart price">49,99</div>
            <div class="itempart qty"><input type="number" name="qty-14587" class="qty" size="2" min="0" max="100" value="0" maxlength="3"></div>
        </li>

        <li class="itemwrapper product-14588">
            <div class="itempart thumbnail"><img src="..."/></div>
            <div class="itempart pinfo">
                <div class="title"><h5>Product Title</h5></div>
                <div class="description">Product Description</div>
            </div>
            <div class="itempart price">69,99</div>
            <div class="itempart qty"><input type="number" name="qty-14588" class="qty" size="2" min="0" max="100" value="0" maxlength="3"></div>
        </li>

        [ ... ]

        <li class="itemwrapper product-14602">
            <div class="itempart thumbnail"><img src="..."/></div>
            <div class="itempart pinfo">
                <div class="title"><h5>Ottional Insurance</h5></div>
                <div class="description">Add an optional Insurance</div>
            </div>
            <div class="itempart price">29,99</div>
            <div class="itempart qty"><input type="checkbox" name="check-14602" class="qty" value="1"></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How to catch the product ids with their quantity with php to have stored data to add them to cart or likely?
Is it possible to select posted content with asteristk? Like `$_POST['product-*']`

Comment: This sounds a lot like "Can you do my homework for me?"
Show some code you have tried already. If you don't know where to start, search for ```php and form values```.

Comment: I just want to get a starting point. i know how the values are send with post, but i dont know how to call values with variable names

Comment: You could name the input fields like ```products[36][quantity]```

Comment: Then i need to update the input name with js depending on the input field value?

Comment: I am assuming you are creating these listings yourself by code, using data from a database. This would make it pretty easy to create the correct names for the input fields on the fly.